# how to group a column by it's values into 3 groups according to a range of numbers

Tags: r

I learning the basics of R and i'm trying to group a column according to a number of ranges. my column is BMI and i want to group the values in it such as underweight, healthy, overweight and obese. Can i please know how to do it? my data frame is weight_log.

Comment: Welcome - what did you try so far? Please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to ask a good question on R. In particular, please edit your question to include the ouput of ``dput(data)`` and your desired output. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to achieve your goal using R, but you are encouraged to show your own attempts to solve the problem when you post questions on StackOverflow to help us troubleshoot the issue/s.

Here is a similar example using [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/learn/) functions that might help you get started:

```
# Load libraries
library(tidyverse)

# Generate some fake data for the example
subjects <- data.frame(height = rnorm(100, 1.6, 0.2),
                       weight = rnorm(100, 75, 20))

# Calculate BMI and categorise subjects (per wikipedia)
subjects %>%
  mutate(BMI = weight / (height^2)) %>%
  mutate(`BMI category` = case_when(
    BMI < 15 ~ "Very severely underweight",
    BMI >= 15 & BMI < 16 ~ "Severely underweight",
    BMI >= 16 & BMI < 18.5 ~ "Underweight",
    BMI >= 18.5 & BMI < 25 ~ "Normal",
    BMI >= 25 & BMI < 30 ~ "Overweight",
    BMI >= 30 & BMI < 35 ~ "Moderately obese",
    BMI >= 35 & BMI < 40 ~ "Severely obese",
    BMI >= 40 ~ "Very severely obese")
  )
#      height    weight      BMI              BMI category
#1   1.600551  90.82957 35.45588            Severely obese
#2   1.673910  90.08658 32.15111          Moderately obese
#3   1.284048  47.01420 28.51456                Overweight
#4   1.474780 113.51028 52.18918       Very severely obese
#5   1.778946  90.02104 28.44581                Overweight
#6   1.353927  65.38778 35.67025            Severely obese
#7   1.492418  75.08285 33.71010          Moderately obese
#8   1.567819  51.66703 21.01947                    Normal
...
```